# Ajax and Validator is not working together

Tags: jsf, validation

When I am trying to insert a validator to a selectOneMenu element containing a ajax listener in JSF, the ajax listener begins to not working. The following is my JSF snipplet specific to issue I am talking:

```
<h:selectOneMenu id="metalCodes" converter="metalCodeConverter" required="true" requiredMessage="#{lang.metalStockIntroducing_metalCode_req_txt}" value="#{metalStockIntroducingProcessesBean.metal.metalCode}">
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Please select..." noSelectionOption="true" />
        <f:selectItems value="#{metalStockIntroducingProcessesBean.metalCodesMenu}" />
        <f:ajax listener="#{metalStockIntroducingProcessesBean.changeMetalType}" event="change" execute="metalCodes" render="metalTypesMenu" immediate="false"/>
        <f:validator validatorId="densityValidator"/>
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

What would you friends recommend me to do in order to make the validator and ajax listener works collaborately in a h:selectOneMenu JSF element?

Comment: Sure that the validator didn't just throw a validator exception? By the way, you tagged "ajax4jsf" but I am not seeing an a4j tag anywhere. Are you really using Ajax4jsf (part of RichFaces) or not? Read the tag description/info if you're unsure what it is.

Comment: Dear BalusC, you are right. My poor knowledge about my JSF let me write something misdirecting. When I see the tags on the page, the one of the proper should be A4J. However, I was wrong and it should be Ajax. Sorry for the misleading information. I won't repeat that mistake. By the way, what do you think I should do for solving issue? Thank you...

Comment: I have edited the tags and removed the A4J tag.

Comment: Are you sure that the validator didn't just throw a validator exception?

Comment: Actually, I am developing my code in the debugging mode and it never falls to the validator class for that component. When I put the validator to the component, the ajax listener begins to not functioning which is functioning fully without the validator. I used the validator in a different component which is not including ajax listener and it looks like that it is working fine without throwing an exception and I can watch the whole processes in the debugging (which is actually falling to debug). I think I have a problem in making it worked collaborately with the ajax listener or vice versa.

Comment: You were right I were receiving an exception. I realized it when I carefully investigated it. The reason that I didn't realized it at first sight is it is trying to implement the validator class immediately when I am trying to change the selectOneMenu and didn't fall to debugging somehow in NetBeans. Sorry for making people busy with my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They ought to work fine together. The ajax listener method will only not be invoked when the validator threw an exception. Make sure that your validator isn't incorrectly doing that. Make sure that you're re-rendering the `<h:message>` or `<h:messages>` associated with the input component as well so that you get notified of any faces messages during an ajax request. Or at least read the server logs, any queued-but-not-displayed faces messages will be logged there.

Comment: Now I realized that using the validator strategy for the selectOneMenu component won't be so suitable for me due to its dynamic behavior in every change which I didn't realize before your warnings. I should use an attribute strategy for my case. However, I am stuck with an another problem in retrieving the attributes value in the validator class. I'll open an another issue o this. Thank you BalusC for your awesome helps.